# How to destructure Array of object and append into new Array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning JavaScript, Now I am playing around with topics incomprehensible to me,
I have simple API call Where I get some kind of data, my aim is to convert existing array and combine into one whole array. As in the example below, What would be the best solution to this problem? thanks in advance. P.S data is dynamic where can be more then two variations

```js
//The existing array I want to change
let TestVariation = [{
        NameValueList: [{
                Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
                Value: [
                    "12"
                ]
            },
            {
                Name: "Shoe Width",
                Value: [
                    "G"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        NameValueList: [{
                Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
                Value: [
                    "9"
                ]
            },
            {
                Name: "Shoe Width",
                Value: [
                    "D"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]








//The result I want to get
let result = [{
            Name: "US Shoe Size (Women's)",
            Value: [
                "12",
                 "9"
            ]
        },
        {
            Name: "Shoe Width",
            Value: [
                "G",
                "D"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You might want to consider changing the question title to **How to Compress a nested Array of an object API Response  using JavaScript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, is to flatten and compress the array. Which involve series of steps. For simplicity, I'll use vanilla javascript and break it into steps, so you can get ideas on how to tackle a similar problem onward.

> Firstly, We need to flatten out the data and make it into the desired structure. For that, I'll use an array method called [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
// let TestVariation = [{...}, {...}];
// overwrite TestVariation or use a new variable

function flatVariations (eachVariationObjectInArray) {
  return eachVariationObjectInArray.NameValueList
}

TestVariation = TestVariation.map(flatVariations)
console.log(TestVariation) // [Array(2), Array(2)]

// flatten the array into one array
TestVariation = TestVariation.flat();
console.log(TestVariation) // [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

> Secondly, we need to compress the data. And for that, we could create a collection for the unique identifiers such as ['Shoe Width', 'US Shoe Size (Women's)'] which we could then use to organize and compress the given data.. or we use an array method called [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
// The above continuation
TestVariation.reduce((variations, testVariant) => {
  // find the new testVariant if its already existed
  const currentVariant = variations.find(variation => variation.Name === testVariant.Name);
  // If: doesn't exist, then add to variations
  if (!currentVariant) variations.push(testVariant);
  // Else: Map through variations, find by name and compress variations
  else {
    variations = variations.map(variation => {
      if (variation.Name === testVariant.Name) {
        return { ...variation, Value: [...variation.Value, ...testVariant.Value] }
      }
      return variation
    })
  }

  return variations;
}, [])
```

In Summary,

```
// let TestVariation = [{...}, {...}];
function flatVariations (eachVariationObjectInArray) {
  return eachVariationObjectInArray.NameValueList
}
TestVariation = TestVariation.map(flatVariations)
TestVariation = TestVariation.flat();
TestVariation = TestVariation.reduce((variations, testVariant) => {
  const currentVariant = variations.find(variation => variation.Name === testVariant.Name);
  if (!currentVariant) variations.push(testVariant);
  else {
    variations = variations.map(variation => {
      if (variation.Name === testVariant.Name) {
        return { ...variation, Value: [...variation.Value, ...testVariant.Value] }
      }
      return variation
    })
  }

  return variations;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays provide the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method which will help you convert an array into another object; in other words, you could get each element of the first array and begin to modify a second array (called the memo) with the structure you intend to do.